# Hide Value in input when it's zero in angular Js

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular object item.add_value = 0 bind into the

```
<input type="number" ng-model="item.add_value"   ng-change="sumUp(item)" min="0" max="10000000000" />
```

In order to do the calculation I have to use type="number" not type="text"

Then my question is how to hide the content of the input when the value is 0?

Comment: Converting strings to numbers in JavaScript is trivial. As to your second question: I'm not of the opinion that this is a good idea. Why wouldn't you want to display the value if it equals zero?

Answer (score 7):

I just had this same problem and found a way to fix/improve on @dubadub's answer, so I'm sharing my version of his directive:

```
.directive('hideZero', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            ngModel.$formatters.push(function (inputValue) {
                if (inputValue == 0) {
                    return '';
                }
                return inputValue;
            });
            ngModel.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {
                if (inputValue == 0) {
                    ngModel.$setViewValue('');
                    ngModel.$render();
                }
                return inputValue;
            });
        }
    };
})
```

You just use it by adding the `hide-zero` attribute to your inputs.

Comment: This is the better solution as the cursor remains (setting text-indent you lose the cursor), and you don't modify the actual value (we just want to change was is displayed, not the underlying model).

Answer (score 4):

The simplest (and the weirdest) way to do it is to use ... CSS! Consider this:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="item.add_value" 
        ng-class="{zero: item.add_value === 0}"
        ng-change="sumUp(item)" 
        min="0" 
        max="10000000000" />
```

and CSS:

```
.zero {
   text-indent: -7px;   
}
```

Not sure it will be appropriate for you, but this is definitely fun and can work if you adjust indent for your font size and input padding.

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/2gRzdY7DVwrPdNGoD0Fq?p=preview

**UDP**. One more version using directive:

```
.directive('hideZero', function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element) {
            element.on('input change', function() {
                if (this.value === '0') {
                    this.value = '';
                }
            })
        }
    };
});
```

and use it like:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="item.add_value" 
       ng-change="sumUp(item)" 
       hide-zero
       min="0" 
       max="10000000000" />
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/nrE3vEW2NSuLYeZuKIjO?p=preview

Comment: Yes, that's why I said this is simplest approach. If it was not a 1am I would try to make a directive with `$parsers` and `$formatters`. This is how you should attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: @Ricc Here is one more simple version with custom directive: http://plnkr.co/edit/nrE3vEW2NSuLYeZuKIjO?p=preview

Comment: I am not so sure about the syntax but in the <input> is hide-zero but in the directive is call 'hideZero'? so directive will the Cap letter and auto separate the word?

Comment: Yes, in HTML you use snake-case, but in javascript it's translated to camelCase.

Comment: Do you mind answer this question for me ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26552647/compare-array-value-after-sort-angular-js

Comment: I find that if the model value is defined ($scope.item=[];   $scope.item.add_value=0 ) in the app this solution does not work.

Answer (score 2):

I think, the most best approach is in using `ngModelController` because it is not uses DOM (we just in data layer, not in view, we need bind as usual except 0) and very strait-forward. It helps adjust binding between model and it's view in way we need:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'World';
});

app.directive('hideZero', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
         link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {

           modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {

             if (inputValue === 0) {
               return '';
             }         

             return inputValue;         
           });
         }
    }
});
```

See more https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController.

Working plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/Zatou8lLx23xwXd1x9hd?p=preview.

Comment: thanks for the Answer, but I think @dfsq 's solution is what I try to get, urs is a bit inversed

Comment: Do you mind answer this question for me ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26552647/compare-array-value-after-sort-angular-js

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ng-show` or `ng-hide` depending on how you want the semantics.

I would recommend [ng-hide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide), because its more intuitive and semantic in my opinion:

```
 <input type="number"
        ng-hide="item.add_value == '0'"
        ng-model="item.add_value"
        ng-change="sumUp(item)"
        min="0" 
        max="10000000000" />
```

but you could use:

[`ng-show`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow):

```
 <input type="number"
        ng-show="item.add_value != '0'"
        ng-model="item.add_value"
        ng-change="sumUp(item)"
        min="0" 
        max="10000000000" />
```

Comment: But if you do ng-hide, it will hide the whole input right? I only want to hide the 0 value.          And my calculation doesnt work after add in "ng-if" I think that will recreate the object which let item.add_value lose its refferece

Comment: @Ricc right, it would hide the entire input element.

Comment: What do you mean by hide only the zero value?

Comment: The correct solution, I think, is to trap the error when you perform the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.item = {
    add_value: 0
  };

  $scope.$watch('item.add_value', function() {
    if ($scope.item.add_value === 0) {
      $scope.item.add_value = "";

    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="firstCtrl">
    <input type="number" ng-model="item.add_value" ng-change="sumUp(item)" min="0" max="10000000000" />


  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Ricc you can use  `$scope.$watch`

Answer (score 0):

Actually the easiest solution would be setting the min value to > 0 like 10?

```
<input type="number" ng-model="item.add_value" ng-change="sum_Up(item)" min="10" max="10000000000" /> <br />
```

Answer (score 0):

I let it be string, but parse it when calculating:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="item.add_value"   ng-change="sumUp(item)" min="0" max="10000000000" />
{{total}}
```

JS:

```
var getRealValue = function(val){
    if(val === ''){
        return 0;
    }else{
        return parseFloat(val);
    }
};
$scope.sumUp = function(val){
   $scope.total = getRealValue(val);
};
```