# Set Angular input value to empty if value equals zero?

Tags: angular

Is there an easy way to set the value of an input blank/empty if the value equals zero (0)? I came across this AngularJS question here, [Hide Value in input when it's zero in angular Js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26537792/hide-value-in-input-when-its-zero-in-angular-js), but couldn't find anything for Angular 2+.

It would only need to be done on load of the page. I realize I could use a setter in the component, but wondering if there is something that could be put on the input itself.

Could this be done with a directive?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a template variable.

```
checkInputValue(input) {
  input.value = input.value == '0' ? '' : input.value;
}
```

and then

```
<input #input (keyup)="checkInputValue(input)" />
```

Edit for onload :

```
import { ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core'

// ...

export class Component implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('input') input: ElementRef

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    let inputValue = this.input.nativeElement.value;
    inputValue = inputValue == '0' ? '' : inputValue;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for something that can be done onload of the page. I edited my question.

Comment: Thanks. Your example does work. Do you know if a directive or property could be put directly on the input in the `component.html` rather than having logic inside the `component.ts`?

Comment: Hmm, I haven't tested this but you could try with the value attribute directive

`<input #input [value]="input.value == '0' ? '' : input.value  " />`

Answer (score 1):

If you want it done on page load, you could do this:

```
<input type="number" (ngModelChange)="data = $event === 0 ? '' : $event" [ngModel]="data" >
```

This will prevent the value from ever being 0, regardless of when.

Comment: The following doesn't work for me: `<input type="number" class="form-control" name="constructionYear" [(ngModel)]="vm?.propertyCoveragesTab.dwelling.constructionYear" #constructionYear="ngModel"
                required pattern="^(18|19|20)\d{2}$" maxlength="4" (ngModelChange)="vm?.propertyCoveragesTab.dwelling.constructionYear = $event === 0 ? '' : $event" />`

Comment: You cannot have parenthesis around ngModel. Make sure you follow the example

Comment: I removed my parenthesis around ngModel but the zero value still gets set: `<input type="number" class="form-control" name="constructionYear" [ngModel]="vm?.propertyCoveragesTab.dwelling.constructionYear" #constructionYear="ngModel"
                required pattern="^(18|19|20)\d{2}$" maxlength="4" (ngModelChange)="vm?.propertyCoveragesTab.dwelling.constructionYear = $event === 0 ? '' : $event" />`

Comment: You're not following the example. see here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tjz49w?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Got it. Your example works for me after page load if I manually type in 0. However, it doesn't appear to work on page load: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z3fhq2?file=app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

To make it work on load, Modifying the ngModel would be suffice:

```
<input type="number" [ngModel]="data == '0' ? '' : data" >
```